# android listview say "New" if user hasnt clicked on item position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listview, basically I would like to have the `Listview` populated and display a `TextView` that says "New" if the user has not clicked on that position yet, and then make the `TextView` visibility set to gone after the user has clicked on that `Listview` item. could anyone help me?

I have tried quite a bit of messing with some codes, of course with trial and error, comes erasing the code so I wasnt able to show you everything that I have tried. This is the last thing I tried:

```
        // selecting single ListView item
    final ListView lv = getListView();



    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long ide) {

            if (lv.isPressed(view.hasFocus(position))) { 
                newjob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            } else { 
                newjob.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            } 


               vib.vibrate(40); 

                // Starting new intent 
                try { 
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                        SingleMenuItemActivity.class); 
                in.putExtra("jobInfo", JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString()); 
                in.putExtra(pays, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(job, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(ready_at, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(due_by, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(customer_reference, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
```

Comment: don't expect people to do all the work for you

Comment: sorry, I wasnt trying to get fed witha golden spoon or anything, just wanted to ask how would i go about to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, simply override the [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Change your TextView's visibility to gone
        view.findViewById(R.id.textView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

**Updated from new code**

It looks like you are using a ListActivity or ListFragment. If so, I recommend using onListItemClick() instead of onItemClick() since it is already set up:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    view.findViewById(R.id.textView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I would then also need to know the position of what tab was clicked so it would disappear accordingly.

Comment: Does each row have its own text view?

Comment: Not nessecarily its own textview, the listview recycles the textview for every tab it populates.

Comment: Indeed ListView recycles its rows, but the row will be built from one row layout so you can use findViewById() inside the row (in this case the row is `view`).

Comment: Very nice Sam! what you suggested actually does work however, the TextView is dissapearing in the wrong positions lol. Ill try to work around what you suggested and report back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I had updated my first answer. Does `view.findViewById(R.id.textView).setVisibility(View.GONE);` change the wrong TextView? The second parameter in onItemClick() (in my case `view`) is the already the row at `position`.

Comment: No it doesnt, its perfect. Now all I have to do is setup some Sharedpreferences so when I exit out of the app and go back in, it will remember which ones has been clicked on. Thanks again Sam, Couldnt have done it without your help!

Comment: I noticed one more thing and updated my answer again. Glad I could help!